# Why is this wrong: Du findest Helfe und Unterstutzung da?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

The sentence to translate is

"You find help and support there."

My wrong answer was:
"Du findest Helfe und Unterstutzung da"

Apparently, the correct answer is:

"Sie finden dort Hilfe und Unterstützung."

Why was I wrong?

Comment: "Sie können da Hilfe und Unterstötzung finden." <- So hätte ich es übersetzt, bin ich aber kein Muttersprächler. Es gibt mehrere Fehler, die ich in Ihrem Satz sehen kann: "Hilfe" und nicht "Helfe", und bitte nutzen Sie Akzente.

Comment: @peterhsaysreinstateMonica  *Unterstötzung* üst äber nücht gönz rüchtüch geschrüben.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Entschuldigung, das war ein Typo :-) Und jetzt kann ich es schon nicht fixen. Es war aber ein Komment und keine Antwort. Ich könnte das Komment löschen.

Comment: @peterhsaysreinstateMonica  Aber ja, das habe ich schon verstanden. Ich fühlte mich nur zu einem Scherz provoziert, weil schon der Beispielsatz in der Ausgangsfrage so auffällige Buchstabierfehler hat.

Answer (score 1):

In English, "help" is both a verb (to help = helfen) and a noun (the help = die Hilfe) - and in this example it is used as a noun. 
For the word order: While it is quite flexible in German, it is just very unnatural to put the adverbial of place to the end of the sentence (unless perhaps with certain cases of emphasis).

And of course, the noun Unterstützung has an umlaut (ultimately from the verb "stützen")  ...

Answer (score -3):

It is wrong for several reasons.
First, the word should be "Hilfe" not "Helfe".
Second, the final word should be "dort" not "da".

So, I believe the following is a correct alternative:

"Du findest Hilfe und Unterstutzung dort."